# Trying to import but getting "Cannot find module 'clone'."

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I'm importing clone.js with `import * as clone from 'clone'` into Angular 2. I have it in my package.json dependencies, and it imported fine into node_modules.

In the output I'm getting `Cannot find module 'clone'.` This all works in another project, but not in my current one. I must be missing something here. What could it be?

Comment: try to remove `npm_modules` and run `npm install` again

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't resolve the problem. And I'm having even more problems with a couple of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire `node_modules` folder and re-install

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

> Do it second time if the first installation is failed

Comment: I tried this a few times. It didn't work. Wondering if it may have something to do with an older version of Angular or Angular-CLI that I am using.